# Neural network performance evaluation

Tags: neural-networks, model-evaluation

I'm just getting started with NN in tensorflow/keras, and need some basic guidelines for what to do.

I'm going to use pretrained model, and set of random images - totally random, few (~20) of them. Now, **I want to evaluate how model is performing.**

I would like to generate some plots or score that would show, lets say low values -> indicating that **model is not trained to recognize this kind of objects**, and high values when predictions are good.

**What should I keep track of?** Overall model prediction certainty? It's not done via model.validate - rigt? Validation is made with validation dataset with correct labels, right?

I know its a broad question, but any answer will help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when my neural network doesn't learn?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn)

Comment: It's a little hard to tell with the information you provided. What task are you aiming to solve? The metric to be used will differ depending on that answer alone.

Comment: @Seankala I'm aiming to do transfer learning. So I wanted to check, how. some pretrained model is performing with a dataset. To check whether it was trained (hence can recognise) to recognize similar objects, or whether new dataset is completely abstract to it.